# Big-O notation runtime: Cracking the Coding Interview example

Tags: recursion, runtime, big-o, coding-efficiency

I mainly just want to confirm my understanding. The following a big-o notation problem from Cracking the Coding Interview. The answer key says runtime is "O(b) or O(n). The recursive code iterates through b calls, since it subtracts one at each level."

So I understand that the part of the function thats power(a, b-1) is equal to O(b) or O(n). **Then would the first "a" be constant number in the line "a * power(a, b-1)"?**

I know that we have to drop constants when we have a big-o of something like O(constant * b), which just becomes O(b).

```
int power(int a, int b){ 
    if(b < 0)
       return 0; //error
    else if(b == 0)
       return 1; 
    else
       return a * power(a, b-1)
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `power` function is just computing the power of some input integer `a` raised to the `b` power.  It does this by simply multiplying `a` by itself `b` times, and then returning that value.  The number of function calls does not really have anything to do with the value of `a`, but rather only with the value of `b`.  So, this function behaves like `O(b)`.  We can also rename `b` to `n` and call this `O(n)`, which is what you probably be more likely to see.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation! Can you vote up my question? I can't vote up your answer since I don't have 15 reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clearest way to explain this would be to call out that "a" is a variable.  You did not have do some computer instruction "a" number of times.

You can also see "b" is also a variable.  But in the case of "b", it also controls the number of times your recursive function is called.  So you did have to execute some computer instruction "b" number of times.  How many instructions doesn't matter as long as that value is constant.  Your program has no other variables what impact the number of instructions executed.

So your function is O(b) or O(n) assuming your n = b (since this is the input that affects how long your program will take to complete.)

Just keep in mind, it's all about estimating the number of instructions that has to be executed.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation! Can you vote up my question? I can't vote up your answer since I don't have 15 reputation points.